# Overriding QDateTimeEdit

Tags: c++, qt, date

I would like to write a widget to edit a date (+time) with one of the following formats :

- doy/yyyy (+hh:mm:ss)
- doy/yy (+hh:mm:ss)

where doy is the number of the day in the year (between [1;365] or [1;366] depending on the year).

In this widget, I would like to have a features provided by QDateTimeEdit :

- the written date to always be valid (e.g the user should not be able to write 367/2020)
- I would like be able to use the wheel and up/down arrows to increase/decrease a given section

Do you have any idea of how to do that ? QDateTimeEdit widget source code is so complicated, it may be a simpler solution to do that.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried already? QTextEdit if I remember correctly can parse regular expressions on input for example, sou you could restrict first the input on numbers and the slash. After inputing you can parse it easily yourself. First find out if you have a leap year and then look at the number. If its ok, it is valid, if not remove the input e.g.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with a lineEdit with a validator base on regexes, but It would have to implement section/separator feature to implement wheel and key events. So I started to backport the QDateTimeEdit source code, but it's very complicated, so I think it may not be the good solution :/

Comment: Ok, thats a tough one. Maybe use two QSpinBoxes for that use case?

Comment: You're right, it's a fallback solution. I just asked in cas of :)

Comment: Have you tried using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#displayedSections-prop with one of the pre-supplied date/time formats?

Comment: Yes I read about that. Problem is that the sections cannot be extended with a custom one (unless I missed something).